# VBA set rng = Range(c.validation.formula1) returns "Nothing" on office 365

Tags: excel, vba, validation

The code runs fine on Excel 2019, but when i try to run it on office 365 it returns rng as nothing on this line:

```
Set rng = Range(c.Validation.Formula1)
```

it does get the formula correctly but seems to not evaluate the formula. if I add Application.Evaluate I get the same problem. Full code below.

```
Function ListSourceRange(c As Range) As Range
Dim vType, rng As Range

On Error Resume Next       'ignore error if no validation
vType = c.Validation.Type
On Error GoTo 0            'stop ignoring errors

If vType = 3 Then
    'try to get a source range...
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range(c.Validation.Formula1)
    On Error GoTo 0
End If
Set ListSourceRange = rng 'source range, or Nothing if no range found
```

End Function

Comment: How does `c.Validation.Formula1` look for that specific cell? Do you test **the same workbook** on both Excel versions?

Comment: If you comment out the second `On Error Resume Next` what happens?  What exactly is the value of `c.Validation.Formula1`?

Comment: Yes, using the same workbook, cell on both Excel versions.

Comment: One possible formula is like this it uses named ranges etc. =IF(NOT(ISERROR(INDIRECT("KITCHEN"&"product_category.value."&VLOOKUP(J7,'Dropdown Lists'!$A$1:$B$16000,2,FALSE)&".product_subcategory.value"))),INDIRECT("KITCHEN"&"product_category.value."&VLOOKUP(J7,'Dropdown Lists'!$A$1:$B$16000,2,FALSE)&".product_subcategory.value"),"")